# Сравнение 2-х массивов

Tags: c#

Дано два массива, первый:

```
DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\N");
FileInfo[] localFiles = dinfo.GetFiles("*.zip");
```

Второй:

```
 string[] downloadFiles = GetFileList();
```

Структура идентична, необходимо выбрать элементы содержащиеся в "downloadFiles" за исключением тех что есть в "localFiles".

Comment: что хранится в `downloadsFiles`? полные пути? просто имена файлов?

Comment: имена файлов. Example.xml.zip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Здесь подойдет [функция `Enumerable.Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var files = downloadFiles.Except(localFiles.Select(lf=>lf.Name));
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за оперативный ответ)